# How to set the theme of a MenuFlyout in UWP?

Tags: winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I know how to set the theme of an entire page with the RequestedTheme property.
But I was wondering how do I explicitly set the theme for a MenuFlyout from c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I was able to solve this by

```
Style s = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Style { TargetType = typeof(MenuFlyoutPresenter) };
s.Setters.Add(new Setter(RequestedThemeProperty, ElementTheme.Dark));
myMenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle = s;
```

Answer (score 1):

`MenuFlyout` doesn't inherit `FrameworkElement` class. If you want change visualization of your flyout you can use `MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle` property.

```
    <Style x:Key="MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle" TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
        <Setter Property="RequestedTheme" Value="Dark"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeHighBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutBorderThemeThickness}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutPresenterThemePadding}" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutThemeMinWidth}" />
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutThemeMaxWidth}" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutThemeMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="MenuFlyoutPresenterScrollViewer"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                        VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                        IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                        IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                        ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}"
                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw">
                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                        <Border x:Name="MenuFlyoutPresenterBorder"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

and use it for your fluout:

```
            <MenuFlyout MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle="{StaticResource MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle}">
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="one"/>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="two"/>
            </MenuFlyout>
```